# Merge 5V 24V 3.3V tags with power-rail

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

The tags associated with a voltage are back. SE discourages the deletion (burnination) of tags. The problem with these tags is they don't really define a group of questions well (a 5V tag could describe many many different types of circuits).

[Delete the 24V, 12V, (and maybe 5V, 3.3V) tags and discontinue use of tags associated with a voltage](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/delete-the-24v-12v-and-maybe-5v-3-3v-tags-and-discontinue-use-of-tags-assoc)

These had been cleaned up before, and they are back.
There are probably a few hundred of these. I propose we create a new power-rail tag and merge them with that.

The other option is we could delete them, if we cleaned them and had a really good reason for deletion.

Comment: This is an interesting proposal. I've long favored deleting these tags outright, but as you've noted they tend to reappear and are on a lot of questions -- so it might be better to handle them by merging them into a single, better tag. "power-rail" is a decent name for a replacement, or perhaps "supply-voltage" would work instead.

Comment: not sure about "power-rail" just some people around the world call Busbar power rail which if you think about it is correct logically is it quite litterly a rail for power. maybe just a voltage-level tag because if there tagging with a specific voltage the OPs would seem to think the voltage is important to the question.

Answer (score 5):

5v and 3.3v can also refer to logic levels.

Comment: That is true, so maybe it would be good to go through and label those questions as 5v-cmos or 5v-ttl or something like that

Comment: That would work

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but as a beginner I don't think I will identify them to use them instead of 5v or 3.3v tags (both power-rail and logic-level but I think power rail is better) , but I like the idea of merging them.